# Present modal view controller from different view? ModalViewController being hidden by other views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I present a modalViewController from a different view controller?

I am currently displaying my modal view like this:

```
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

But, I want to

```
[OtherViewController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

Because part of it is being hidden by another viewController that is above it and manages the "self" view.

Comment: I'm not really understanding the question, if you could please elaborate about your problem :S ... try doing that in your post for everyone to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it should work, but maybe you are in a corner case.

Try adding a static method to your delegate like:

```
+ (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

Where you do something like

```
[parentViewController presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

And use it to present the modal view directly from the parent VC.

Anyway, if you still have a problem, give us some code :-) or your app archi.

Answer (score 0):

It simply does not work b/c there is now such class method declared in a UIViewController class.

You are trying to call (note the + sign in front):

```
+ (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

UIViewController class only provides implementation for an instance method (note the - sign in front):

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

What should this tell you?

It tells you that you need to have a link to a live `OtherViewController` object to be able to invoke `presentModalViewController` on it, otherwise there is no `View` hierarchy the compiler can comply with.